# Implementing a confirm delete (archive) with StimulusReflex not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, confirm, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

Using Bootstrap, StimulusReflex and Discard in a Rails application, I'm trying to implement a confirm modal before the actual reflex action is called. As it is now, this does not work and bypasses the modal. Here is the html/erb code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 pl-4 pr-0 mt-4">
      <% if is_admin? && product.persisted? %>
        <%= link_to('Archive', '#', class: 'btn btn-outline-danger hoverable-border',
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', reflex: 'click->Products#archive', id: product.id }) %>
```

and the reflex #archive method:

```
  def archive
    @product ||= Product.find(element.dataset.id)
    @product.discard
    morph '#products-content', render(partial: 'shared/products/admin/index', locals: { products: @product.omd_practice.products })
  end
```

What would be the best way to implement this? Do I need to call a StimulusJS action that performs the confirm modal and then fires the reflex? I'm new to Stimulus overall so a bit hazy on this.

Comment: The `data-confirm` attribute is something Rails provides for links/button that make requests. A reflex is something distinct.
Indeed adding a stimulus action and calling the reflex from there after the prompt is the way to go. Having said that, it would be cool to have support for that, if you are interested in pairing on a PR on stimulus reflex let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the `confirm:complete->` and it works perfectly. No need for creating a StimulusJS controller.

Comment: I've just read in the documentation (rails-ujs) that confirm:complete  fires no matter if you click 'cancel' or 'ok'. Am I doing something wrong?